# sagepay account for LIVE and TEST mode both

Tags: payment-gateway, opayo

we have one site running with sagepay **LIVE** mode now.
we created another site with which we need to use **same** sagepay account with **TEST** mode.

We have Encryption password which works for both LIVE and TEST mode URLS.

So can we use one sagepay account be used with both "TEST" and "LIVE" account and it does not affect "LIVE" transactions.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPLY FROM SAGEPAY PEOPLE -

Thank you for your email.

The test and live Sage Pay accounts are completely separate so you can use them both at the same time if you wish, and they do not affect each other.

Customer Service Advisor

Sage Pay